# Using SetWindowPos with multiple monitors

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, screen, user32

Using `user32.dll` and C# I wrote the method that you see below. Using a process handle for a window, it will set the window position at a provided `(x, y)` location.

However, in a multi-monitored environment the code below sets the window position to the primary monitor, only. I would like to be able to select which monitor, too.
Can someone please explain how this can be accomplished using `SetWindowPos` or perhaps a combination with another `user32.dll` function?

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int X, int Y, int cx, int cy, int uFlags);

private const int SWP_NOSIZE = 0x0001;
private const int SWP_NOZORDER = 0x0004;
private const int SWP_SHOWWINDOW = 0x0040;

public static void SetWindowPosition(Process p, int x, int y)
{
    IntPtr handle = p.MainWindowHandle;
    if (handle != IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        SetWindowPos(handle, IntPtr.Zero, x, y, 0, 0, SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
    }
}
```

**Solution based upon Jimi's comment.**

Here is my monitor configuration:

[image]

Observe that I have a secondary monitor to the left of my primary monitor. After reading the Virtual Monitor link that Jimi provided I discovered that to move windows to the secondary monitor that I must use a negative x-value because it is left of the primary monitor's origin (top left corner, or `(0, 0)`).

Therefore, if I want to have my window position set to the secondary monitor's <0,0> coordinate, that I must SUBTRACT the x-width of the secondary monitor from the origin of the primary monitor, like this:

```
(0, 0) - (1920, 0) = (-1920, 0)
```

Now, when I call `SetWindowPosition` in my client code, I call it like this:

```
SetWindowPosition(Process p, -1920, 0);
```

Note: I do not know what you would do if the monitors have different resolutions. That is a more complex topic and not a question that I am asking. Also, I did not see a need to explore deeper in to the topic as the simple example above solved all of my issues.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

**System Displays disposition and VirtualScreen**

In a Windows System, the [Primary Screen](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.screen.primaryscreen) (programming perspective) is the Display device which has its upper left corner position set at **`Point(0,0)`**.

This implies that the Displays positioned on the **left** of the Primary Screen, will have **negative** `X` coordinates (the `Y` coordinate could be negative if the Display is in Portrait layout).
The Displays on the **right** will have **positive** `X` coordinates (the `Y` coordinate could be negative if the Display is in Portrait layout).

**Displays on the *Left* of the Primary Screen**:
*In other words, Displays that have a **negative* `Point.X`** *origin*.
The `Point.X` origin is the sum of all of the preceding `Screens[].Width`, subtracted from the `Point.X` origin coordinate of the Primary Screen.

**Displays on the *Right* of the Primary Screen**:
*In other words, Displays that have a **positive* `Point.X`** *origin*.
The `Point.X` origin is the sum of all of the preceding `Screens[].Width`, **Primary included**, added to the origin `Point.X` coordinate of the Primary Screen.

---

**Important note about Dpi Awareness**:
If the application is not DPI Aware, all these measures can be compromised by the virtualization and automatic DPI Scaling performed by the System. All measures will be *uniformed* to a default 96 Dpi: the application will receive scaled values. This also includes the values retrieved from non-Dpi ware Win32 API functions. See:

[High DPI Desktop Application Development on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hidpi/high-dpi-desktop-application-development-on-windows)

Enable support for all targeted Systems in the **`app.manifest`** file, uncommenting the required sections.

**.NET Framework prior to 4.7.2**:
Add/Uncomment the [DpiAware and DpiAwareness sections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/mt846517(v%3Dvs.85)) in the **`app.manifest`** file.

**.NET Framework prior to 4.7.2+**:
The [PerMonitorV2 Dpi Awareness](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/high-dpi-support-in-windows-forms) mode can be set in the `app.config` file (available from Windows 10 Creators Edition).

**.NET6+**:
Add or edit the `<ApplicationHighDpiMode>` property in the Project's file (`.csproj`), e.g.:

```
<ApplicationHighDpiMode>PerMonitorV2</ApplicationHighDpiMode>
```

For all possible settings, see [MSBuild reference for .NET Desktop SDK projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/msbuild-props-desktop#applicationhighdpimode)

In this scenario, `app.manifest` is only used to specify which System versions your app supports. `app.config` is not used.

See also:

[DPI and Device-Independent Pixels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/dpi-and-device-independent-pixels)
[Mixed-Mode DPI Scaling and DPI-aware APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hidpi/high-dpi-improvements-for-desktop-applications)

---

Example:
Consider a System with 3 Monitors:

```
PrimaryScreen             (\\.\DISPLAY1):  Width: (1920 x 1080)
Secondary Display (Right) (\\.\DISPLAY2):  Width: (1360 x 768)
Secondary Display (Left)  (\\.\DISPLAY3):  Width: (1680 x 1050)

PrimaryScreen: 
     Bounds: (0, 0, 1920, 1080)      Left: 0      Right: 1920  Top: 0  Bottom: 1080
Secondary Display (Right): 
     Bounds: (1360, 0, 1360, 768)    Left: 1360   Right: 2720  Top: 0  Bottom: 768
Secondary Display (Left): 
     Bounds: (-1680, 0, 1680, 1050)  Left: -1680  Right: 0     Top: 0  Bottom: 1050
```

[image: Multi Display Disposition 1]

If we change, using the System applet, the Primary Screen reference, setting it to `\\.\DISPLAY3`, the coordinates will be modified accordingly:

[image: Multi Display Disposition 1]

**Virtual Screen**

The Virtual Screen is a virtual display, which dimensions are represented by:
**Origin**: the origin coordinate of the left-most `Screen`
**Width**:  the sum of all the `Screens` Widths.
**Height**: the Height of the highest `Screen`.

These measure are reported by [SystemInformation.VirtualScreen](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.systeminformation.virtualscreen)
The Primary Screen `Size` is reported by [SystemInformation.PrimaryMonitorSize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.systeminformation.primarymonitorsize)
All the Screens current measures and position can also be retrieved using [Screen.AllScreens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.screen.allscreens) and inspecting each `\\.\DISPLAY[N]` properties.

Using the preceding example as reference, in the first disposition, the `VirtualScreen` bounds are:

```
Bounds: (-1680, 0, 3280, 1080)  Left: -1680  Right: 3280   Top: 0  Bottom: 1080
```

In the second disposition, the `VirtualScreen` bounds are:

```
Bounds: (0, 0, 4960, 1080)  Left: 0  Right: 4960   Top: 0  Bottom: 1080
```

**Window Position inside a Display area**:

The [Screen class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.screen?) offers multiple methods that can be used to determine in which screen a specific window is currently displayed:

[`Screen.FromControl([Control reference])`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.screen.fromcontrol)
Returns the `Screen` object that contains the largest section of the specified `Control` reference.

[`Screen.FromHandle([Window Handle])`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.screen.fromhandle)
Returns the `Screen` object that contains the largest section of the Window\Control referenced by an `Handle`

[`Screen.FromPoint([Point])`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.screen.frompoint)
Returns the `Screen` object that contains a specific `Point`

[`Screen.FromRectangle([Rectangle])`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.screen.fromrectangle)
Returns the `Screen` object that contains the largest section of the specified `Rectangle`

[`Screen.GetBounds()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.screen.getbounds) (overloaded)
Returns a `Rectangle` structure that references the Screen Bounds that contain:

- a specific `Point`
- largest section of the specified `Rectangle`
- A `Control` reference

To determine the `\\.\DISPLAY[N]` in which the current Form is shown, call (for example):

```
Screen.FromHandle(this);
```

To determine in which Screen a secondary Form is shown:
(Using the Displays layout shown in the sample images)

```
var f2 = new Form2();
f2.Location = new Point(-1400, 100);
f2.Show();
Rectangle screenSize = Screen.GetBounds(f2);
Screen screen = Screen.FromHandle(f2.Handle);
```

`screenSize` will be equal to the `\\.\DISPLAY3` Bounds.
`screen` will be the `Screen` object representing the `\\.\DISPLAY3` properties.

`screen` object will also report the `\\.\DISPLAY[N]` name of the `Screen` in which `form2` is shown.

---

**Obtain the `hMonitor` Handle of a Screen object**:

The [.NET Reference Source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Screen.cs,442) shows that the **`hMonitor`** is returned calling **`[Screen].GetHashCode();`**

```
IntPtr monitorHwnd = new IntPtr([Screen].GetHashCode());
```

Or using the same native Win32 functions:

[MonitorFromWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-monitorfromwindow), [MonitorFromPoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-monitorfrompoint) and [MonitorFromRect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-monitorfromrect)

```
[Flags]
internal enum MONITOR_DEFAULTTO
{
    NULL = 0x00000000,
    PRIMARY = 0x00000001,
    NEAREST = 0x00000002,
}

[DllImport("User32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern IntPtr MonitorFromWindow(IntPtr hwnd, MONITOR_DEFAULTTO dwFlags);

[DllImport("User32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern IntPtr MonitorFromPoint([In] POINT pt, MONITOR_DEFAULTTO dwFlags);

[DllImport("User32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern IntPtr MonitorFromRect([In] ref RECT lprc, MONITOR_DEFAULTTO dwFlags);
```

- To detect Window movements between Monitors, you can handle [`WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-windowposchanged) messages, call **`MonitoFromWindow`**, then [GetScaleFactorForMonitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellscalingapi/nf-shellscalingapi-getscalefactorformonitor) to determine whether there's a DPI change and react to a new setting, eventually.

**Obtain a Handle of the device context of a Screen**:
A generic method to retrieve the hDC of any Display available.

The Screen coordinates or Screen Device can determined using one of the methods previously described when only a specific Screen reference is required.

The [Screen.DeviceName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.screen.devicename) property, which is retrieved calling [GetMonitorInfo()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getmonitorinfow), passing a [MONITORINFOEX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-monitorinfoexw) struct (see the declaration at the bottom) can be used as the **`lpszDriver`** parameter of GDI's [CreateDC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-createdcw) function. It will return the hDC of the display that [Graphics.FromHdc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.fromhdc) can use to create a valid Graphics object, which will allow to paint on a specific screen.

Here, assuming at least two Displays are available:

```
[DllImport("gdi32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
internal static extern IntPtr CreateDC(string lpszDriver, string lpszDevice, string lpszOutput, IntPtr lpInitData);

[DllImport("gdi32.dll", SetLastError = true, EntryPoint = "DeleteDC")]
internal static extern bool DeleteDC([In] IntPtr hdc);  

public static IntPtr CreateDCFromDeviceName(string deviceName)
{
    return CreateDC(deviceName, null, null, IntPtr.Zero);
}


Screen[] screens = Screen.AllScreens;
IntPtr screenDC1 = CreateDCFromDeviceName(screens[0].DeviceName);
IntPtr screenDC2 = CreateDCFromDeviceName(screens[1].DeviceName);
using (Graphics g1 = Graphics.FromHdc(screenDC1))
using (Graphics g2 = Graphics.FromHdc(screenDC2))
using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 10))
{
    g1.DrawRectangle(pen, new Rectangle(new Point(100, 100), new Size(200, 200)));
    g2.DrawRectangle(pen, new Rectangle(new Point(100, 100), new Size(200, 200)));
}

DeleteDC(screenDC1);
DeleteDC(screenDC2);
```

Declare `MONITORINFOREX` like this:
(`dwFlags` is set to `0x00000001` if it's the primary Monitor)

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public unsafe struct MONITORINFOEXW
{
    public uint cbSize;
    public RECT rcMonitor;
    public RECT rcWork;
    public uint dwFlags;
    public fixed char szDevice[32];
}
```