# C# Check orientation of second screen

Tags: c#, multiple-monitors

I have written a code which rotates my 3rd display.

Now I want to check first, in which orientation the display currently is.

I wrote the following code:

```
    int scrRectHeight = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height;
    int scrRectWidth = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width;

    if (scrRectHeight > scrRectWidth)
    {
        Display.Rotate(3, Display.Orientations.DEGREES_CW_90;
    }
    else
    {
        Display.Rotate(3, Display.Orientations.DEGREES_CW_180;
    }
```

This works fine, but it only works for the primary display. I can't find a definition to change it to a second display. How can I change it, or is there another method? Thanks!

Comment: Consider to not use PrimaryScreen if you meant to look at the properties of the second screen, Screen.AllScreens[1].

Comment: @HansPassant I didn't understand how to use AllScreens. It's so simple! Thanks

Comment: @HansPassant Could you add it as an answer so I can mark it?

Comment: I have a hard time identifying the brain-bug in this code.  Just share what you discovered in your own post and mark it as the answer.

Comment: [Using SetWindowPos with multiple monitors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53012896/c-sharp-user32-using-setwindowpos-with-multiple-monitors?answertab=active#tab-top)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not "SecondaryScreen" property.

Try this instead:

```
int secondRectHeight = Screen.AllScreens[1].Bounds.Height;
int secondRectWidth = Screen.AllScreens[1].Bounds.Width;

if (secondRectHeight > secondRectWidth)
{
    Display.Rotate(3, Display.Orientations.DEGREES_CW_90;
}
else
{
    Display.Rotate(3, Display.Orientations.DEGREES_CW_180;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, But this is to complicated. Look at Hans Passant comment.

Comment: Updated the sample.