# Open Form on Primary Screen

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Form that opens in the fourth monitor connected to a PC. From this form I have to open another Form, but on the main monitor.This is the simple code I use:

```
oWin = new Form2();
System.Windows.Forms.Screen oScreen =  System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen;
oWin.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
oWin.Location = oScreen.WorkingArea.Location;
oWin.Show();
```

But oWin(Form2) always opens on the same monitor as the source form, ie on the fourth monitor.I also tried to insert the code in the Load method of Form2 but it does not work.

Comment: [Using SetWindowPos with multiple monitors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53026765/7444103).

Answer (score 0):

Use `Bounds` instead of `WorkingArea`:

```
oWin = new Form2();
System.Windows.Forms.Screen oScreen =  System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen;
oWin.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
oWin.Location = oScreen.Bounds.Location;
oWin.Show();
```