# how to stop SizableToolWindow going under windows 10 taskbar when maximised?

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-10

I am developing a windows form application where one of the forms uses the border style of `SizableToolWindow` however this causes issues when you have the windows taskbar set to the side of the screen.
[image: form going under taskbar]

Is there any possible way to stop this happening without moving the taskbar?

**Solved**
Changed the window border to "sizeable"

Comment: You could set the Form's MaximumSize to the current screen WorkingArea.Size: `this.MaximumSize = Screen.FromHandle(this.Handle).WorkingArea.Size;` (but, cannot test this right now). Tool Windows are not supposed to be maximized, though.

Comment: Your method works however it leave about a 15px gap on the right and bottom of the form

Comment: That's the transparent border size. Add it to the maximun size. There's a SystemInformation property that reports that measure. It could be `SystemInformation.BorderSize` or `SystemInformation.Border3DSize`. See here: [Using SetWindowPos with multiple monitors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53026765/7444103) for more informations on the subject.

Comment: @ToddOwen Any reasons why you are using a `ToolWindow` when what you actually want to display is not a `ToolWindow` ? This works perfectly with a standard window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the window border to "sizeable"

**suggested**

> Any reasons why you are using a ToolWindow when what you actually want to display is not a ToolWindow ? This works perfectly with a standard window – Franck