# Getting a pixel color at screen coordinates and detecting for color change

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm trying to create an application to perform some a task for me. Basically, I'd like to be able to assign a point on my screen with a hotkey (F12) which would save the color at that point.

This pixel color changes and then resets back to its original color often.

Throughout the runtime of the application, each time that color changes away from it's original color, it opens a msgbox letting me know that the color has changed again.

I've done a lot of googling, but for the life of me, I can't figure this out.

Here's what I have so far.

I have a timer2 that detects my hotkey (F12), grabs the color, and even grabs the coordinates of my mouse:

```
Private Sub Timer2_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer2.Tick
    For i = 1 To 255
        result = 0
        result = GetAsyncKeyState(i)
        If result = -32767 Then
            If i = 123 Then
                Dim myBmp As New Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height)
                Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(myBmp)
                g.CopyFromScreen(Point.Empty, Point.Empty, myBmp.Size)
                g.Dispose()
                Label1.Text = MousePosition.X.ToString & "," & MousePosition.Y.ToString
                PictureBox1.BackColor = myBmp.GetPixel(MousePosition.X, MousePosition.Y)
                'Label1.BackColor = myBmp.GetPixel(MousePosition.X, MousePosition.Y)
                myBmp.Dispose()

            End If
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Right now, that code errors out if I try to capture the pixel color on one of my other monitors (I have more than 1 monitor):
"An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll
Additional information: Parameter must be positive and < Width."
at this line: PictureBox1.BackColor = myBmp.GetPixel(MousePosition.X, MousePosition.Y)

Also, given that I am able to somewhat get the coordinates of the mouse, I have no idea how to keep my application monitoring those coordinates in a resource-light manner (without the mouse having to stay at that pixel location or the form being in focus) for the color changes. Can someone help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the <kbd>F12</kbd> portion working, as well as the timer, on my multi-monitor setup

```
<DllImport("user32.dll")>
Shared Function GetAsyncKeyState(ByVal vKey As Keys) As Short
End Function

Private savedColor As Color
Private savedPosition As Point
Private timer As New Threading.Timer(AddressOf timerCallback)
Private timerInterval As Integer = 100

Private Sub setPositionAndColor(ByRef position As Point, ByRef color As Color)
    Using myBmp As New Bitmap(SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Width, SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Height)
        Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(myBmp)
            g.CopyFromScreen(Point.Empty, Point.Empty, myBmp.Size)
        End Using
        position = Cursor.Position
        color = myBmp.GetPixel(position.X, position.Y)
    End Using
End Sub

Private Sub timerCallback(state As Object)
    If GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.F12) <> 0 Then
        setPositionAndColor(savedPosition, savedColor)
        Me.Invoke(
            Sub()
                Label1.Text = $"{savedPosition.X}, {savedPosition.Y}"
                PictureBox1.BackColor = savedColor
            End Sub)
    Else
        Dim currentColor As Color
        Dim currentPosition As Point
        setPositionAndColor(currentPosition, currentColor)
        If currentPosition = savedPosition AndAlso currentColor <> savedColor Then
            MessageBox.Show("!")
        End If
    End If
    timer.Change(timerInterval, -1)
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    timer.Change(timerInterval, -1)
End Sub
```

After running it, I found it to be a little choppy. But it seems to do what you want to do.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to just copy the one pixel that you need instead of creating such a large bitmap in memory every time? :) - After all `Graphics.CopyFromScreen()` lets you specify coordinates and size of the area which to capture.

Comment: @VisualVincent yes. I had just copied OP code and made it work. OP can optimize it as such. The main changes I made which allowed it to work are `SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Width` and `Cursor.Position`

Comment: Saw that. Just suggested it as an additional improvement. By the way, I forgot to say "Nice answer!" :)

Comment: Thank you! Marked this as answer. Unfortunately I didn't know that Graphics.CopyFromScreen() was more optimized. I'll try to google on how to use that instead :).

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do can be pretty slow when using GDI. A great way of implementing such a thing would be to look into something like SharpDX and utilize DirectX to capture the screen for you and just loop through pixels in an array to get their colors.

https://github.com/sharpdx/SharpDX-Samples/blob/master/Desktop/Direct3D11.1/ScreenCapture/Program.cs

I realize the code is in C#, but it's very similar to VB and I'm sure it wouldn't be very difficult to convert it.

Answer (score 0):

A method using [RegisterHotkey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registerhotkey) to install a system-wide Hotkey which activates a procedure that captures the color under the Cursor in any Screen.

When the keyboard key, registered as the Hotkey, is pressed, the Window (or the thread) that registered it will be notified, no matter if the Window has the focus, is minimized or in another screen.

When the Hotkey is pressed, the Screen where the Cursor is located is identified using the [Screen.FromPoint()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.screen.frompoint?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.Screen.FromPoint);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework&view=netframework-4.7.2) method.
See the answer in [Using SetWindowPos with multiple monitors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53026765/7444103) for more informations about the methods related to the Screen object and the Screens/VirtualScreen coordinates.

The [CreateDC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-createdcw) function is then used to obtain the device context of the Screen corresponding to the Cursor position and the [GetPixel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-getpixel) function to capture the Color of the pixels under the Cursor.

No bitmaps are created at any point.

Notes:

- The registered Hotkey must be unregistered using the [UnregisterHotKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-unregisterhotkey) function.
- The handle created by the CreateDC function must be released using the [DeleteDC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-deletedc) function.
- When the Hotkey is pressed, a [WM_HOTKEY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/inputdev/wm-hotkey) message is sent to the Window (or the thread) that registered it. We need to override WndProc to receive the notification. See the notes in the MSDN Docs related to the `WM_HOTKEY` message about the interpretation of values represented by `wParam` and `lParam`.
- If the Hotkey corresponds to the one we registered, an Action (here, named **`HotkeyPressed`**) is called. The color under the Cursor is set as the BackColor of a PicureBox control (here, named `PicureBox1`).
- Since the F12 key was mentioned, is useful to note that this key is reserved by the Debugger (the current debugger or the kernel-mode debugger), it shuld not be used. Of course, it can be associated with a key modifier (Control, Alt, Shift).
- If more Hotkeys are registered, the corresponding Identifier (here, a Field named **`myHotkeyID`**) must be incremented/changed.

---

Insert the following code in a Form of choice.
The Hotkey (**`F11`**) is registered in the `Form.Load()` event and unregisterd in the `Form.FormClosed()` event.

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Security
Imports System.Security.Permissions

Private Const WM_HOTKEY As Integer = &H312
Private myHotkeyID As Integer = 327680
Private myHotkeyModifiers As RegHotkeyModifiers = 0
Private currentScreen As Screen
Private cursorPosition As Point = Point.Empty
Friend Shared HotkeyPressed As Action

Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
    HotkeyPressed =
    Sub()
        currentScreen = Screen.FromPoint(cursorPosition)
        Me.PictureBox1.BackColor = PixelColorFromScreen(currentScreen, cursorPosition)
    End Sub
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim result = RegisterHotKey(Me.Handle, myHotkeyID, myHotkeyModifiers, Keys.F11)
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_FormClosed(sender As Object, e As FormClosedEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosed
    UnregisterHotKey(Me.Handle, myHotkeyID)
End Sub

<SecurityCritical>
<SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Flags:=SecurityPermissionFlag.UnmanagedCode)>
Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As Message)
    Select Case m.Msg
        Case WM_HOTKEY
            If CType(m.WParam, Integer) > 0 Then
                Dim keyPressed As Keys = CType(CType(m.LParam, Integer) >> 16, Keys)
                Dim modifiers = CInt(m.LParam) And &HFF
                If myHotkeyID = CInt(m.WParam) AndAlso CInt(myHotkeyModifiers) = modifiers Then
                    Select Case keyPressed
                        Case Keys.F11
                            cursorPosition = Cursor.Position
                            HotkeyPressed()
                    End Select
                End If
            End If
            Exit Select
    End Select
    MyBase.WndProc(m)
End Sub
```

Win32 functions declarations and helper methods:

```
<Flags>
Friend Enum RegHotkeyModifiers As UInteger
    MOD_ALT = &H1
    MOD_CONTROL = &H2
    MOD_SHIFT = &H4
    MOD_WIN = &H8         ' WINDOWS key was held down. Reserved for use by the operating system.
    MOD_NOREPEAT = &H4000 ' Keyboard auto-repeat does not yield multiple hotkey notifications.
End Enum

<DllImport("user32.dll")>
Friend Shared Function RegisterHotKey(hWnd As IntPtr, ActionHotkeyId As Integer, fsModifiers As RegHotkeyModifiers, VirtualKey As Integer) As Boolean
End Function
<DllImport("user32.dll")>
Friend Shared Function UnregisterHotKey(hWnd As IntPtr, ActionHotkeyId As Integer) As Boolean
End Function

<DllImport("gdi32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)>
Friend Shared Function CreateDC(lpszDriver As String, lpszDevice As String, lpszOutput As String, lpInitData As IntPtr) As IntPtr
End Function

<DllImport("gdi32.dll", SetLastError:=True, EntryPoint:="DeleteDC")>
Friend Shared Function DeleteDC(<[In]> hdc As IntPtr) As Boolean
End Function

<DllImport("gdi32.dll", SetLastError:=True)>
Friend Shared Function GetPixel(hdc As IntPtr, nXPos As Integer, nYPos As Integer) As UInteger
End Function

Friend Function CreateDCFromDeviceName(deviceName As String) As IntPtr
    Return CreateDC(deviceName, Nothing, Nothing, IntPtr.Zero)
End Function

Private Function PixelColorFromScreen(screen As Screen, position As Point) As Color
    Dim screenDC As IntPtr = CreateDCFromDeviceName(screen.DeviceName)
    Dim pixel As UInteger = GetPixel(screenDC, position.X, position.Y)
    Try
        Return Color.FromArgb(CType(pixel And &HFF, Integer),
                              CType(pixel And &HFF00, Integer) >> 8,
                              CType(pixel And &HFF0000, Integer) >> 16)
    Finally
        DeleteDC(screenDC)
    End Try
End Function
```