# Dealing with computer monitors[Extends]

Tags: c#, winforms

In the beginning, **I have a 4-form desktop program** that wants to display every form on a screen depending on a **unique identifier** for this **screen**, for example Form 1 on the screen with ID etc and Form 2 on the screen with the ID ....

If all form is run correctly, i need a Way to check whether the screens are connected throughout the program life cycle so that if  disconnect one, get a message in the name of the form in which it was displayed and prevent this form from moving to another screen

I tried the following method:

```
Screen.ALLScreen []
```

However, this method does **not** provide an **ID** depending on the *screen*, but depending on the *sequence of screen connections to the computer*.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Form2 F2= new Form2();
        Form3 F3 = new Form3();
        this.Location = new Point(Screen.AllScreens[0].Bounds.X, Screen.AllScreens[0].Bounds.Y);
        F2.Location = new Point(Screen.AllScreens[1].Bounds.X, Screen.AllScreens[1].Bounds.Y);
        F3.Location = new Point(Screen.AllScreens[2].Bounds.X, Screen.AllScreens[2].Bounds.Y);
        F2.Show();
        F3.Show();}
```

//here i will   check all screens if they are connected throughout the program life cycle

```
public void checkScreen(){`// rescan all screen`check if there any screen disconnected`if it happened  `send message  form name and close the form or minmize it`}
```

Comment: Welcome!  Would it be possible to post some more code? [mcve].  This will help us help you.  Good luck

Comment: You'll have to combine this: [WM_POWERBROADCAST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/power/wm-powerbroadcast) and this: [WM_DISPLAYCHANGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/wm-displaychange). These notes may also help: [Using SetWindowPos with multiple monitors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53026765/7444103).

Comment: With regard to identifying a particular display: I guess you have to search and look for a library that can obtain EDID/DisplayID data for each display. EDID/DisplayID data _can_ provide the serial number of a display device (unless the device provides incomple EDID/DisplayID data lacking serial number information). If there is no such .NET library, you might want to look for a native DLL with C-style function exports which you could P/Invoke. If there is not even such a native DLL to be found, i guess you have to code this yourself :-(

Comment: ... and you could register for Power changes notifications: [RegisterPowerSettingNotification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registerpowersettingnotification), which could be combined with: [RegisterPointerInputTarget](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registerpointerinputtarget) (to *centralize* the messages management).

Comment: You can read EDID data with WMI (I just posted a sample in C++, but it is easier in C#) I have only 1 monitor so I cannot test with several ones, but I get for my monitor : `Instance Name = DISPLAY\PHLC085\4&20634529&0&UID65793_0
   User Friendly Name = 247ELH
   Manufacturer Name = PHL
   Product Code ID = C085
   Serial Number ID = AU01307001613`

Comment: can you  send me a link your post