# Capture a picture from a second screen

Tags: c#, screen-capture

I'm making a universal application for myself (mainly to learn and challenge myself), I want to capture the top left of my second monitor (2nd is on the left side), but I only know how to capture on my main monitor

```
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100);
            Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(rect.Width, rect.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bm);
            g.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, bm.Size);
            pictureBox1.Image = bm;
```

Comment: Change the coordinates for `g.CopyFromScreen()` to the area you want to capture. If your primary monitor is the one on the right, and the upper-left corner of that monitor are at 0, 0, then your left (secondary) monitor's coordinates are going to be negative. Capture an area at -500, 0 and see what you get in your PictureBox.

Comment: Read the notes here: [Using SetWindowPos with multiple monitors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53026765/7444103). Don't rush over the DPI Awareness part.

Answer (score 1):

"Change the coordinates for `g.CopyFromScreen()` to the area you want to capture. If your primary monitor is the one on the right, and the upper-left corner of that monitor are at 0, 0, then your left (secondary) monitor's coordinates are going to be negative. Capture an area at -500, 0 and see what you get in your PictureBox."

- https://stackoverflow.com/users/62576/ken-white