# Screen AllScreens sequence not matching with control panel display setting

Tags: c#, api, multiple-monitors

I want same monitor sequence as shows in control panel

When I used Screen.AllScreens it is giving sequence 1 for 2, 2 for 3 and 1 for 3. Also I tried WMI however could not find solution where i can get the monitor number same as control panel display.

In control panel=>Display Settings=>Identify shows monitor sequence.

Comment: Do you have screenshots / configuration file contents you can share?

Comment: I don't understand *1 for 2, 2 for 3 and 1 for 3*

Comment: Read the notes here: [Using SetWindowPos with multiple monitors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53026765/7444103). Don't skip the DPIAwareness part.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VkWCB.png Here you can see monitor position in  (control panel=>Display Settings=>Identify ) 2 - 3 -1. So i am expecting Screen.AllScreens API should give some properties which can tell me monitor sequence and it number. For Example her monitor sequence 1 number is 2. I am not getting this number 2 anywhere nor sequence of it.