# Set Delta in a WM_MOUSEWHEEL message to send with PostMessage

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, winapi, postmessage

How can I set the `Delta` parameter of the `WM_MOUSEWHEEL` message and send the message to a Windows using `PostMessage`?

My code:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, int wParam, int lParam);

const uint WM_MOUSEWHEEL = 0x020A;

private int MAKELPARAM(int p, int p_2)
{
    return ((p_2 << 16) | (p & 0xFFFF));
}
```

Now I'm using it like this:

```
IntPtr hwnd1;
hwnd1 = FindWindow(null, "NoxPlayer");
Point location = new Point(1205,411);
PostMessage(hwnd1, WM_MOUSEWHEEL, 0, MAKELPARAM(location.X, location.Y));
```

When I do it like that I have:

[image]

The Windows doesn't scroll because delta is `0`.

Comment: What is it you are trying to accomplish? Send scroll input to a window? You might want to look into `SendInput` (also user32.dll)

Comment: Im trying just to send scroll mouse button to window , without focos window. Right and left click button works well. I have only problem with scroll because of this zDelta parametr.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `WHEEL_DELTA` is the default value of a mouse wheel increment (for mouse controllers with no freely-rotating wheel). This value is returned by [SystemInformation.MouseWheelScrollDelta](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.systeminformation.mousewheelscrolldelta).
It's usually set to `120`, but it can be a different value.
When the Delta value is positive, it indicates that the mouse wheel is rotated forward, causing a Window to scroll upwards, the opposite when Delta is negative.
In the code sample, **`directionUp`** and **`directionDown`** determine this direction.

The Delta can be set to a fraction or a multiple of the base increment (can be used to fine-tune the scrolling).  See the Docs about [`WM_MOUSEWHEEL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-mousewheel) for more information.

In the example, the wheel increment is divided in half (the **`float multiplier`** argument of the `MAKEWPARAM` *macro* is set to **`.5f`**).

The Window identified by **`[Handle]`** doesn't need to be activated (it doesn't need to be the Foreground Window).

The [Cursor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.cursor) position represents Screen coordinates. The application should be DpiAware to handle Cursor positions and Screen coordinates correctly.
See the notes about the VirtualScreen and how DpiAwareness is involved here:

[Using SetWindowPos with multiple monitors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53026765/7444103).

```
int directionUp = 1;
int directionDown = -1;

// Scrolls [Handle] down by 1/2 wheel rotation with Left Button pressed
IntPtr wParam = MAKEWPARAM(directionDown, .5f, WinMsgMouseKey.MK_LBUTTON);
IntPtr lParam = MAKELPARAM(Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y);

PostMessage([Handle], WM_MOUSEWHEEL, wParam, lParam);
```

---

```
internal const uint WM_MOUSEWHEEL = 0x020A;

[Flags]
public enum WinMsgMouseKey : int
{
    MK_NONE = 0x0000,
    MK_LBUTTON = 0x0001,
    MK_RBUTTON = 0x0002,
    MK_SHIFT = 0x0004,
    MK_CONTROL = 0x0008,
    MK_MBUTTON = 0x0010,
    MK_XBUTTON1 = 0x0020,
    MK_XBUTTON2 = 0x0040
}

[DllImport("User32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
internal static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

internal static IntPtr MAKEWPARAM(int direction, float multiplier, WinMsgMouseKey button)
{
    int delta = (int)(SystemInformation.MouseWheelScrollDelta * multiplier);
    return (IntPtr)(((delta << 16) * Math.Sign(direction) | (ushort)button));
}

internal static IntPtr MAKELPARAM(int low, int high)
{
    return (IntPtr)((high << 16) | (low & 0xFFFF));
}
```

Comment: It looks like that your example works only for forward wheeling. Backwards does not work, as delta remains positive as a result to `MAKEWPARAM` call.

Comment: @Henri Nope, that's what the `direction` parameter is for. If you pass a negative value, you scroll down, otherwise you scroll up.

Comment: I've tested your code and it did not work. I changed the `MAKEWPARAM` signature to `MAKEWPARAM(delta, button)` where delta can either be positive or negative and the function returns `(delta << 16) | button`.

Comment: @Henri Well, that's exactly what this code is doing. You pass a Delta (absolute value - no sign) and a direction `int directionUp = 1; int directionDown = -1;`. You can apply the Direction directly to the Delta value (making it signed). It's the same exact thing, just a different implementation: you do it beforehand or later, it doesn't change the result. This code is tested.

Comment: @Henri Here, the implemetation accepts a direction because the Delta is calculated based on the System setting - which is a User preference - and overrides it to provide a custom behavior, in `int delta = (int)(SystemInformation.MouseWheelScrollDelta * multiplier);`, so you can perform *smoother* scrolling if needed. The direction, which is provided as parameter, is applied later. -- You can also write it as `int delta = (int)(SystemInformation.MouseWheelScrollDelta * multiplier) * Math.Sign(direction); return (IntPtr)((delta << 16) | (ushort)buttons);`