# Modifying windows mouse scroll properties programmatically

Tags: c#, winforms

Is there a way to programmatically modifying mouse scroll properties in Windows?  If a user sets horizontal scrolling to e.g. 3 because it is handy for web browsing, this unfortunately also affects controls like NumericUpDown so they also scroll in steps of 3 characters, e.g. 1-4-7-10 etc. instead of 1-2-3-4 etc.. Ideally it should be possible to set this under the controls properties but apparently MS hasn't thought about that (unless there's something I've overlooked).

So, is there a way to override this setting programmatically, for a particular control, or maybe just generally, while the control has focus, or something?

Comment: [Set Delta in a WM_MOUSEWHEEL message to send with PostMessage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60213791/7444103). To adapt to the use-case.

Comment: Will take a look at that, thanks!