Winforms - How do I unload non visible controls in a scrollable window?
I'm learning c# & winforms and I have an issue on the app I'm making.
I have a flowlayout containing small pictures box, I made the flowlayout scrollable to have a gallery of sort I can then scroll through.
But when I reach a few hundreds pictures, it fills up my memory (even tho the pictures are already resized very small) and I cant display any more of them.
Is there a way to check that the picbox is in view and unload the ones that aren't ?
Only thing I could find was the VisibleChanged Event but it seems to fire only when the controls is set to be hidden so that won't do. But maybe I missed something.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71042667/virtual-paging-user-controls-and-programmatic-scrolling-in-flowlayoutpanel might give you an idea. But making it "good" is not beginners stuff. If you want to maintain smooth scrolling you need to fiddle with deferring actual loading/unloading of images (with async code for example) as it takes time and some trickery that unneeded loading/unloading does not occur. Like when going directly from first entry to last entry.  You might want to prevent loading most stuff in between.

I'm so new I had no idea what words to even search for... But I see what I need to get it working now (might be a bit too complicated for me right now but I'll figure it out in time)
Thanks a lot !
