# StartPosition CenterScreen doesn't work after resizing the Form in Form.Load

Tags: c#, winforms

In the Form Load event I'm adding some controls to the Form dynamically.
I use this code to resize the Form to adapt its Size to the its new content:

```
this.MaximumSize = new Size(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
this.AutoSize = true;
this.AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
```

It works fine but `StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen` doesn't work as expected:
the Form center position is calculated based on the original size.

Comment: Sure, getting it centered requires handling the difference between the screen size and the window size.  You changed the window size, not centered anymore.  Add `this.CenterToParent();` to do it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to resize the Form using it's [PreferredSize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.preferredsize) property. When you have added new Controls to the Form and these Controls don't fit in client area, the `PreferredSize` is updated to reflect the new size needed to contain them all, but limited to the Form's `MaximumSize` you have set.
Then use the [CenterToScreen()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.centertoscreen) method to center the Form to the current Screen.

[CenterToParent()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.centertoparent), suggested by Hans Passant in comments, has the same effect if the Form is not parented to any other Form: i.e., if it's not shown using the `.Show(this)` method overload; otherwise, it's centered to the Owner Form.

Setting `AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink` (or calling the `SetAutoSizeMode()` method) and **then** setting `AutoSize = true` can have unwanted results.  The more visible is that you cannot resize your Form with normal means anymore. The area occupied by a `StatusStrip` may not be considered etc.

As a note, if your application is not DpiAware, the Screen measures and your Form's Size may be different from what is expected. In case it's not, read about it here:

[High DPI support in Windows Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/high-dpi-support-in-windows-forms)

[These notes about the Screen and VirtualScreen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53026765/7444103) may also be useful:

---

So, add your controls to the Form (maybe in the `Load` handler) then:

```
var screen = Screen.FromHandle(this.Handle);
this.MaximumSize = new Size(screen.WorkingArea.Width, screen.WorkingArea.Height);
this.ClientSize = this.PreferredSize;
this.CenterToScreen();
```