# Checkbox customized to toggle button in winforms is not rendered properly when using different monitors with different resolutions

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox

I customized the checkbox to be rendered as a toggle button which doesn't render properly if I use two monitors with different resolutions, otherwise it renders properly. How can I lock it to be displayed as same in any monitor

[image]

[image]

This is how the custom checkbox looks like,

```
      protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        this.OnPaintBackground(e);
        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
        using (var path = new GraphicsPath())
        {
            var d = Padding.All;
            var r = this.Height - 2 * d;
            path.AddArc(d, d, r, r, 90, 180);
            path.AddArc(this.Width - r - d, d, r, r, -90, 180);
            path.CloseFigure();
            e.Graphics.FillPath(Checked ? Brushes.DarkGray : Brushes.LightGray, path);
            r = Height - 1;
            var rect = Checked ? new Rectangle(Width - r - 1, 0, r, r)
                               : new Rectangle(0, 0, r, r);
            SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(0, 122, 204));

            e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Checked ? brush : (TeamsForm.CurrentBackGroundTheme.Name == DarkBackGround) ? Brushes.WhiteSmoke : Brushes.LightGray, rect);
        }
```

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53026765/10216583) help..

Comment: @JQSOFT Only the DpiAwareness part described there would somewhat help. Here the problem is that using a fixed measure, as the Padding value, doesn't scale well. Or, doesn't scale at all. All measures need to be relative, here. The OP needs to define a section of the Custom/User Control where the Graphics is rendered and recalculate/verify the section ratio (the relation between the parts - current width and height, mainly, but also the relative position of the Graphics inside the section) each time the control is invalidated.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to handle [`Form.DpiChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.dpichanged) event and rescale your control.

However in .NET Framework PMA is rudimentary, to-date it hasn't seen much improvement in .NET Core either.

Comment: How to rescale the control? Which properties do I need to change?

Comment: Your code above contains a number of constants that need to be multiplied by the scale factor. Depending on how involved what you're trying to accomplish you may need to do something like this: https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/blob/62c17fe35b2f00f8156828148a5fbbb910cc52a1/src/System.Windows.Forms.Primitives/src/System/Windows/Forms/Internals/DpiHelper.cs

Comment: Without PMA, you could probably do something like https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/blob/b210331fb67b2362cc1c666ad49911d4666d85e0/GitExtUtils/GitUI/DpiUtil.cs