# How can I check that my Form on which screen is, when I two screens have?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I would like a simple if statement, with I can check, that my Form on which sreen locates.

Something like this pseudo code:

```
If (...my Form locates on the primary screen...) Then
            screenWidth = Screen.AllScreens(0).Bounds.Width
            screenHeight = Screen.AllScreens(0).Bounds.Height
Else
            screenWidth = Screen.AllScreens(1).Bounds.Width
            screenHeight = Screen.AllScreens(1).Bounds.Height
End If
```

Comment: Read the notes here: [Using SetWindowPos with multiple monitors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53026765/7444103)

Comment: @David Yes, thanks! I should use it like this: `Screen.FromControl(Me).Equals(Screen.AllScreens(0))`

Comment: Are you wanting to check if the form is on the primary screen?

Comment: @CaiusJard The primary, or the secondary maybe.  This formula works it now very well:  `If Screen.FromControl(Me).Equals(Screen.AllScreens(0)) Then
            screenWidth = Screen.AllScreens(0).Bounds.Width
            screenHeight = Screen.AllScreens(0).Bounds.Height
Else
            screenWidth = Screen.AllScreens(1).Bounds.Width
            screenHeight = Screen.AllScreens(1).Bounds.Height
End If`

Comment: I don't quite understand why it's not just `Screen.FromControl(Me).Bounds.Width` - you're saying "if the screen the form is on is screen 0 then get screen 0's size, otherwise screen 1" - what if there is no screen 1? What if the form is on screen 2?