# C# WinForms Move Cursor To Other Screen

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, multiple-monitors

I'm using **2 screens in my computer**, and I'm trying to move the cursor programmatically to the other screen using this code in WinForms:

```
private void MoveCursor()
{
    Cursor.Position = new Point(-100000, Cursor.Position.Y);
}
```

This only moves the cursor in the screen the cursor is in, this means the cursor is going always to the 0 position in the current screen but doesn't go further to the next screen.

How can I move it to the other screen? I just want to move it to the far left (x position) in all my 2 screens.

Comment: Read the notes here: [Using SetWindowPos with multiple monitors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53026765/7444103) -- `-100000`? What kind of Screens do you have :)