# Win Form size larger than screen size

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to run my first Win Form C # program on a notebook, but the bottom of my program is below the taskbar. All of my controls are inside a TableLayout Panel with "Percentage" as the size type. How can I solve this?

Obs: I would like to run the windows in `WindowState.Normal`, without having to maximize the window, if possible. Thanks!

[One of the parts of the program that is below taskbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13ACx.jpg)

Comment: `var screen = Screen.FromControl(this); this.Bounds = screen.WorkingArea;` -- Read the notes here: [Using SetWindowPos with multiple monitors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53026765/7444103)

Comment: It looks like the total height of all the controls in this form is bigger than the screen height you need to use a vertical scroll bar, try to set YourTableLayout.AutoScroll to true.

Comment: @Jimi Thanks, I'm gonna try this code and read the notes.

Comment: @jonathana Have some way to adjust the height of the controls automatically according to the monitor, so that I don't have to use the vertical scrollbar?

Comment: @PedroHenrique, In fact, I do not like to use the scroll bar in WinForms and have encountered a lot in such cases, what I would do is check what the screen height including in a `Resize()` event and if the screen height is found below a certain height then arrange the form differently maybe with a lateral layout and increase the width of the form.

Comment: @jonathana Perfect, I understood completely. What I find strange in my case is that this notebook already runs another program that has practically the same controls ( [link](https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/images/003/215/036/original/WhatsApp_Image_2021-04-27_at_13.09.59.jpeg?1619539859) ) as mine, but his is even smaller and everything fit perfectly.