# Working Area showing incorrectly in VB.net

Tags: vb.net

So I am trying to get the screen size without the taskbar, and through reading around I found that the only reliable way was to get the "working area" of the screen (Especially since I might be using multiple screens.), then subtract it from the screen size

Now, my issue is that the working area I am getting is equal to the screen size, which means it is not showing my the actual working area. I have tried some different solutions, and the codes are straight forward.

```
    Dim workingArea = My.Computer.Screen.WorkingArea
```

This would give me back 1920x1080 which is the same as my resolution. I am not using an auto hide taskbar, and I am not sure what's the issue with this, and/or if there is a better way to do what I am trying to do.

Edit: I have tried to use the DPI aware as per the last comment (following the steps in [Using SetWindowPos with multiple monitors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53012896/using-setwindowpos-with-multiple-monitors/53026765#53026765))

I am quite confused why I am not getting the correct number here, any feedback is appreciated.

Edit2:I have tested this code itself in another PC and it was a similar result, I will attempt to install an older version/newer version of visual studio or another .net version, however the issue is still illogical, and no solutions seem to be working (with one or more screens having the exact same feedback.)

Edit3: The task bar does not hide, testing the numbers still shows the same regardless of the number of screens, different resolutions were the same as well.

Comment: What is your Windows, Visual Studio, and the .NET (Core/Framework) version?

Comment: Windows 10, .net 5 and VS Community 2019

Comment: What are the exact values of `My.Computer.Screen.WorkingArea.ToString()` and `My.Computer.Screen.Bounds.ToString()`? I see a 40-pixel difference in the `Height` against both .NET Framework 4.8 and .NET 5.0.

Comment: That returns the working area of the _primary_ screen. Try one of the `Screen.Fromxxx` methods. Like: `Dim workingArea = Screen.FromControl(Me.Handle).WorkingArea`.

Comment: I was getting the exact value for both Working Area and bounds without any difference. Let me try dr.null's suggestion.

Comment: All three methods showed me this: "{X=0,Y=0,Width=1920,Height=1080}"

Comment: Does this happen when you create a new app?

Comment: Read the notes here: [Using SetWindowPos with multiple monitors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53026765/7444103) -- Don't skip the DpiAwareness part.

Comment: So, My.Computer.Screen.Bounds.Height - My.Computer.Screen.WorkingArea.Height
returns zero?

Comment: Yes, it returns zero, with one or more screens having the same effect. (laptop screen)

Comment: Probably not related, but have you set the taskbar to hide automatically?

Comment: Nope :( It shouldn't