# WinForms: Correlate Screen Number to Screen.AllScreens.DeviceName

Tags: .net, winforms

I have a PC with 3 monitors. Each monitor will display different information.

When I launch my `WinForms` application, I will query all the displays using `Screen.AllScreens`, so that I can decide what to shown on which screen.

I always assume the array returned are actually indexed according to the screen number. Means **screen 1**, following by **screen 2** and following by **screen 3**

It had been running without any problem for the past 10 years, until recently the computer was changed. I found that the index is not always correct. Some times it will return **screen 2**, **screen 1**, **screen 3**.

But at the Display are still showing the correct **screen number** when we **Identify** them using Windows 10.

Checking the `DeviceName` returned by `Screen.AllScreens` it shows something like **\\.\DISPLAY2**, **\\.\DISPLAY1**, **\\.\DISPLAY3**.

So I guess I need to correlate the `DeviceName` with the **Screen Number**. May I know what is the best way? Can I assume the `DeviceName` always appears as **\\.\DISPLAY##**, so that I can parse the last digits to decide the **Screen Number**?

Comment: See the notes here: [Using SetWindowPos with multiple monitors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53026765/7444103)

Comment: @Jimi thanks for the link. But I have no problem positioning the display on my screen. I only need to know how to correlate the **Screen Number** with the array returns in ``AllScreens``.

Comment: You can look at the *pictures* :) `Screen.AllScreens` uses [EnumDisplayMonitors(null,null, ..., ...)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumdisplaymonitors) to return that array.