# wpf WindowState = WindowState.Maximized weirdly maximize window

Tags: c#, wpf

[image: pic]

as shown in the picture, `WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;` doesn't fully and correctly maximize the window; it doesn't fill the screen and it shouldn't go over the taskbar either. I used

```
WindowStyle="None"
AllowsTransparency="True"
SizeChanged="Window_SizeChanged"
Title="MainWindow" Height="1000" Width="1500" KeyDown="www_KeyDown"
WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
ResizeMode="NoResiz"
```

which I thought should work.

I didn't change the MaxHeight or Width either, so I am not sure what is happening here.

Comment: The invisible borders are still there. Remove this: `WindowStyle="None"` (to test the difference)

Comment: @Jimi that doesn't make any sense tho cuz I want a custom window style and it still would  look weird

Comment: If you want to *maximize* a borderless Window, you need to calculate its position and size and take into account the invisible borders around it (7 + 1 pixels). It's not hard. Get the current Screen (where you Window is shown or moved to) and use its `WorkingArea` as reference. -- See [the notes here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53026765/7444103) about the Screen coordinates and VirtualScreen layout.

Comment: This issue is quite frequently,  you can look at this to see example of recalculation of the window size https://github.com/6demon89/Tutorial.WPF/blob/master/Tutorial.WPF/MainWindow.xaml.cs