# WinForms : Not able to Maximize Blurred Window

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms

I have a window on which I have some blur effects running.
 I want this window to be maximized so I set the `Window State` field to be `Maximized` in the designer.
But the Window is not maximized and leaves some uncovered area in the top left corner.
 Ive tried multiple `Start Position` settings but none of them solve the problem.
**The Settings**
[image] 
 
 **The Window**
 
[image]

**The code for the blurry Window**

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace WF4
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            this.EnableBlur();
            SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
            SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
            SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);
            BackColor = Color.LimeGreen;
            TransparencyKey = Color.LimeGreen;
            InitializeComponent();
            FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Hllo");
            }
        }

    }
    public static class WindowExtension
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static internal extern int SetWindowCompositionAttribute(IntPtr hwnd, ref WindowCompositionAttributeData data);

        public static void EnableBlur(this Form @this)
        {
            var accent = new AccentPolicy();
            accent.AccentState = AccentState.ACCENT_ENABLE_BLURBEHIND;
            var accentStructSize = Marshal.SizeOf(accent);
            var accentPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(accentStructSize);
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(accent, accentPtr, false);
            var Data = new WindowCompositionAttributeData();
            Data.Attribute = WindowCompositionAttribute.WCA_ACCENT_POLICY;
            Data.SizeOfData = accentStructSize;
            Data.Data = accentPtr;
            SetWindowCompositionAttribute(@this.Handle, ref Data);
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(accentPtr);
        }

    }
    enum AccentState
    {
        ACCENT_DISABLED = 0,
        ACCENT_ENABLE_GRADIENT = 1,
        ACCENT_ENABLE_TRANSPARENTGRADIENT = 2,
        ACCENT_ENABLE_BLURBEHIND = 3,
        ACCENT_INVALID_STATE = 4
    }

    struct AccentPolicy
    {
        public AccentState AccentState;
        public int AccentFlags;
        public int GradientColor;
        public int AnimationId;
    }

    struct WindowCompositionAttributeData
    {
        public WindowCompositionAttribute Attribute;
        public IntPtr Data;
        public int SizeOfData;
    }

    enum WindowCompositionAttribute
    {
        WCA_ACCENT_POLICY = 19
    }

}
```

Comment: Make sure your app is DpiAware and the Form scales to Dpi. -- A border-less Form still has borders, (7+1 pixels), so consider this when you position that window. You can use the current Screen working area as measure (since your app will be DpiAware, you'll be able to read non-virtualized values) and position your Form accordingly -- The notes here may help: [Using SetWindowPos with multiple monitors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53026765/7444103)

Comment: Such is the misery when using undocumented winapi functions.  Try to get ahead by setting the FormBorderStyle property to None and calling EnableBlur() *after* InitializeComponent().

Answer (score 1):

I tested Hans's suggestion and it worked well.

The solution is to set the FormBorderStyle property to None.

[image]

Make sure the background color is Control.

[image]

Calling EnableBlur() after InitializeComponent()：

```
InitializeComponent();
this.EnableBlur();
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I have made an answer. If you don't mind, you could click '✔' to mark my reply as the accepted answer. It will also help others to solve the similar issue.