# Child form opens on first screen when user has dragged the main form to the second screen

Tags: c#, winforms

My Application's Main Form opens on the Laptop (main screen) when it starts. Then user drags it to the other screen (for big display), and opens a child form that is displayed on the Laptop screen rather than Application's Main Form (big display). I want the child form to open on the screen where Application's Main Form is open at the moment.

I tried following options, but they only worked in debug mode and did not work in production

```
ChildForm.ShowDialog((IWin32Window)this.MainForm);
ChildForm.ShowDialog(formMainInstance);
ChildForm.Show(formMainInstance);
```

I know about `FormStartPosition.CenterParent`, but it's not the right option for me. How can I do this?

Comment: When do you set the FormStartPosition to CenterParent? (in code or in the designer)

Comment: I dont want to use FormStartPosition to CenterParent because child form opens on top left corner

Comment: What is this.MainForm? What is this here? What is formMainInstance? What are these coming from? -- The new Form should open where the Owner is located. How should it open on top left corner? You're not setting anything that causes that, unless you have just set `StartPosition` to `Manual` without specifying *where* to start from. -- Could be useful: [Using SetWindowPos with multiple monitors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53026765/7444103)

Comment: In other *words*, you could set: `var screen = Screen.FromControl(this); ChildForm.Location = screen.WorkingArea.Location; ChildForm.Show(this);` where `this` is the Owner Form and `StartPosition` is set to `Manual`.

Comment: @Jimi this.MainForm is Windows Form property ApplicationContext.MainForm that gets or sets the form to use as context. however formMainInstance is the instance of my mainform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code worked for me.

```
var screen = Screen.FromControl(childFormInstance);
var MainFormScreen = Screen.FromControl(_formMainInstance);
ChildForm.Left = MainFormScreen.WorkingArea.Left + 120;
ChildForm.Top = MainFormScreen.WorkingArea.Top + 120;
ChildForm.ShowDialog();
```

1. First I query which screen the child form want to open
2. Then I query which screen my Main form is currently open
3. Then I overwrite the child form screen

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you have 3 options:

1. Use FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;

   ```
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {          
        Form2 child = new Form2();
        child.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        child.ShowDialog(this);
    }
   ```
2. Use FormStartPosition.CenterParent

   ```
   private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {          
        Form2 child = new Form2();
        child.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
        child.ShowDialog(this);
    }
   ```

   }
3. Use FormStartPosition.Manual and pass a point

   ```
       private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {          
        Form2 child = new Form2();
        child.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
        child.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        child.ShowDialog(this);
    }
   ```