# Blank screen on second monitor windows 10

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I am working with 3 devices plugged in a PC (projector, monitor, touchscreen).

I have developed a software application, but I have some issues when displaying it.

The problem is I get a blank screen when try to show the main window on the touchscreen, I am using this code(hope it is helpful) it is inside form load:

```
this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
this.Location = Screen.AllScreens[1].WorkingArea.Location;
this.Size = Screen.AllScreens[1].WorkingArea.Size;
this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None
```

Also I have found out that after re-plugging hdmi cable it works fine without white screen, but when I restart the PC, it happens again.

My question: is it a software problem and can I fix it?

Comment: [Using SetWindowPos with multiple monitors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53026765/7444103)

Comment: I have two identical systems, one is working fine this this code, another does not unless I re-plug third monitor hdmi cable after pc restart. Also white screen appears before form loads