# C# Screen Class member methods cannot open form on secondary display

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

There are some methods from the `Screen` class to retrieve the respective screen, which contains the most area of a control.

They are the:

- Screen.FromRectangle(Rectangle rect)
- Screen.FromControl(Control control)
- Screen.FromHandle(IntPtr hwnd)
- Screen.FromPoint(Point point)

The issue here is that I have a problem getting my second `Form` to be opened in the second monitor. It kept on displaying only on the primary screen. According to the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71052606/how-to-prevent-a-popup-form-from-exceeding-screen-area), the suspect is that the `DpiAware` was not enabled. However, the problem was still not fixed even after I have enabled the `DpiAware`.

To help me to check what was going on, I've added code for debugging. Then, I called/ opened the popup menu on `\\\\.\\DISPLAY2`. Inside of the debug console, the chosen `Screen` for `FromPoint()` was written `\\\\.\\DISPLAY2`. However, the popup menu was still opened on `\\\\.\\DISPLAY1`. Can anyone help me with this issue, please?

Below are the codes example:

Under main form class:

```
//mouseup event handler
private void Form1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    //if RMB clicked
    if(e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        //----set PopupMenu form location----
        popupMenuObj.Location = popupMenuObj.popupMenuLocation((sender as Control).PointToScreen(e.Location));
        //----set PopupMenu form location----

        //process the form location
        popupMenuObj.Location = popupMenuObj.processFormLocation(popupMenuObj.Location);

        //----set PopupMenu cursor location----
        Cursor.Position = popupMenuObj.middleOfPopupMenu(popupMenuObj.Location);
        //----set PopupMenu cursor location----

        //----display the popup menu----
        popupMenuObj.displayPopupMenu(1);
        //----display the popup menu----
    }
}
```

Under popup menu class:

```
//to set cursor to middle of popup menu
public Point middleOfPopupMenu(Point mousePoint)
{
    int theCenterWidth = this.Width / 2;
    int theCenterHeight = this.Height / 2;

    //set the mouse pointer location at middle of PopupMenu
    mousePoint.X += theCenterWidth;
    mousePoint.Y += theCenterHeight;

    return Cursor.Position = mousePoint;
}
```

```
//to set popupmenu location
public Point popupMenuLocation(Point thePoint)
{
    return this.Location = thePoint;
}
```

```
//set popup menu display status
public bool displayPopupMenu(int displayFlag)
{
    switch(displayFlag)
    {
        case 1: //if argument 1 -> display the PopupMenu
            this.Visible = true;
            return true;
        case 0: //if argument 0 -> close the PopupMenu
            this.Visible = false;
            return false;
        default: //by default, no need to display
            return false;
    }
}
```

```
//to process if popupmenu opens exceeding the screen working area
public Point processFormLocation(Point currentPoint)
{
    Point newPoint = new Point();
    int selectedScrWidth, selectedScrHeight; //screen dimension of the selected screen
    Screen selectedScreen;
    int totalXPos, totalYPos; //where the form is located before exceed screen is handled

    //---get screen where point is at---
    selectedScreen = Screen.FromPoint(currentPoint);
    Console.WriteLine("\nSelected screen info: {0}\n", selectedScreen); //for debugging purposes
    //---get screen where point is at---

    //---get selected screen dimension---
    selectedScrWidth = selectedScreen.WorkingArea.Width;
    selectedScrHeight = selectedScreen.WorkingArea.Height;
    //---get selected screen dimension---

    totalXPos = currentPoint.X + this.Width; //mouseXCoor + popupMenu width
    totalYPos = currentPoint.Y + this.Height; //mouseXCoor + popupMenu height

    //if exceed selected screen width and height
    if ((totalXPos >= selectedScrWidth) && (totalYPos >= selectedScrHeight))
    {
        newPoint.X = selectedScrWidth - this.Width;
        newPoint.Y = selectedScrHeight - this.Height;
    }
    //if exceed selected screen width
    else if ((totalXPos >= selectedScrWidth))
    {
        newPoint.X = selectedScrWidth - this.Width;
        newPoint.Y = currentPoint.Y;
    }
    //if exceed selected screen height
    else if ((totalYPos >= selectedScrHeight))
    {
        newPoint.X = newPoint.X;
        newPoint.Y = selectedScrHeight - this.Height;
    }
    else //if x exceed screen, just set the location as is
    {
        return this.Location = Cursor.Position;
    }
    return this.Location = newPoint;
}
```

---

**Update 1**:
As per Jimi's request under the comment section, after creating a simple test project based on given answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71052606/how-to-prevent-a-popup-form-from-exceeding-screen-area), here's what I got:
[image: screenInfo]

Please **note** the reason why the code in the question from the previous [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71052606/how-to-prevent-a-popup-form-from-exceeding-screen-area) has no `Width`, `Height`, and `StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual` defined was because the popup menu is from a class on another `.cs` file where, those specific properties have already been declared in the `PopupMenu.Designer.cs` file. Therefore, I don't feel like redefining was necessary.

---

**Update 2**:
Now that it works, a newer problem arises is that, only when popup menu exceeds right boundary of secondary display, the popup menu was displayed on primary screen. However this didn't occur when I try to open the popup menu when exceeding the height of secondary screen. Example is shown below:

[image: newIssue1]
Above is the case when I try to open the popup menu when exceeding the width of secondary screen. The popup menu opens at the right boundary of primary screen.

[image: newIssue2]
It however worked just fine when I tried the case for exceeding the height of secondary display.

Comment: "Additionally, to further confirm my issue, I have even tried to debug the program. Still, the Screen used was still on \\\\.\\DISPLAY1" -- Debugging is to help you understand why  something happens, it doesn't magically fix anything for you.

Comment: @Blindy -- I think I have misused my words. I have updated the question. Hopefully, its more understandable.

Comment: Can you try to use [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71055631/7444103) exactly as it's written, without any change? Copy it and add it to a test Project. -- Note that the `MouseUp` event is related to the Control where the event is raised, not the Form; the click location is translated to Screen coordinates. -- The popup's `StartPosition` must be `FormStartPosition.Manual`. -- When debugging, write down the measures specified by `SystemInformation.VirtualScreen`, `Screen[0]`, `SystemInformation.PrimaryMonitorSize` and post them here.

Comment: @Jimi -- Updates has been done as necessary.

Comment: All right. Now, take the code you find in that post (take a new copy, don't use what you have), create a new Project, add a Form and add some Controls to it, let them all subscribe to `MouseUp` event using the same handler (`someControl_MouseUp` in that code) and tell me the popup window opens in the primary screen instead of a secodary.

Comment: @Jimi -- Sorry, but which 'that post' are you referring to? -- Weird enough..it works after I have done the test project using the answer from the previous post. However, a newer problem arises. I've updated the post above as necessary.

Comment: The [code you find in your previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71055631/7444103), the same you also linked. Get the current version and use it as it is the way I described before.

Comment: Anyway, I'll give it a look tomorrow. I'll notify you if I change something.