# Start Form1 in the secondary monitor, or move it to it

Tags: vb.net, winforms

How do I get Form1 to open/start in (or move it to) the secondary monitor?
On the keyboard it's Win + Shift + Right.
I have read that "SendKeys.Send" doesn't support the Windows key.

Comment: [StartWindowPosition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.startposition?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) and [Screen class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.screen?view=windowsdesktop-6.0)

Comment: [Using SetWindowPos with multiple monitors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53026765/7444103) -- Don't skip the DpiAwareness part.