# Screen coordinates to show form on the right screen

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to show my form on the screen I'm clicking on.

For this I use a `globalhookMouse` to get the coordinates of my cursor outside my form. I've two screen (1280x1024 and 1680x1050).

I've tried to put my form if my `Cursor.Position.X` is lower than one of my resolution but I get higher value.

This is how I hook my form to show

```
private void GlobalHookMouseDownExt(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Middle)
     {
          this.Show();
          this.TopLevel = true;
     }
}
```

How can I know from which screen I clicked to show my form on the right screen ?

Comment: Read the notes here: [Using SetWindowPos with multiple monitors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53026765/7444103) -- Don't skip the DpiAwareness part.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.screen.frompoint?view=windowsdesktop-6.0

Answer (score 0):

System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens gives you a lot of information about your screens.

You will see that the X can go negative.

int x = System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.X;
int y = System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.Y;

these will always be the coords of where your cursor is at that moment.

the end result would be something like:

```
if (Cursor.Position.X > 0)
{
   this.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0,0);
}

else
{
    this.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(-1920,0);
}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: But if I've two screen, how can I know which screen am I on if my X is like 2342 ?

Comment: You could also do the following: this.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y);                                                        Then the form will start wherever your cursor is at that moment. Please let me know if it works for you.