# c# Is there a function to get Monitor (Primary and Secondary) Scale %?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-3.5

I have WinForms with TableLayoutPanel with rows divided by **%/pixels** inside Toolstrips and other stuff. Problem comes if monitor 4K and scale is set higher than 175%, some layouts rows not properly resize, buttons or toolstrip are barely visible.

Manually I can fix this, but same fix is not suitable for 100% and 200% scale, so I need IF's.

So main question is how to get each monitor scale %? Or at least scale % on that monitor were it was loaded.

Comment: Read the notes here: [Using SetWindowPos with multiple monitors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53026765/7444103) about `GetScaleFactorForMonitor()`; as described`[Screen].GetHashCode()` returns the `HMONITOR` (Handle of a Monitor) that can be used in the function call. Or use `MonitorFromWindow()` or `MonitorFromPoint()` instead -- The scale of the Monitor is not enough, the Font can also be scaled. Your app needs to be DpiAware and handle Font scale on its own terms. A DpiAware application receives Dpi change notifications (a Control can handle `DpiChangedAfterParent`)

Comment: Thanks for reply @charlieface, C-Pound Guru and Jimi.
Similar question almost solves my question as I can get scaling factor for each monitor. DpiAware probably wont help me due I'm on .net 3.5, but thanks for link. Very interesting post.