# VB - SetDesktopLocation, Xpos not working

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to fix a problem with a program `SetDesktopLocation` settings.

Previously, the program is on a dual-monitor PC setup, with the 1st monitor resolution being 1280 x 720. The program's configuration settings are all in a notepad file, which includes refresh time, connection string, and the X-position `Xpos` set to 1280. So that the program will open on the 2nd monitor/TV.

But after a few weeks of inactivity and a change of cable to connect the TV, the program keeps opening to the monitor instead. Everything in the config file is working, just except for the `Xpos` only. I even check back my code to make sure nothing's wrong, but can't find anything off.

```
Imports DAL
Imports System.Configuration
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Data.SqlTypes
Imports System.IO

Public Class frmMain
Dim LocalDAL As New DAL.DataAccess
Dim dr As SqlDataReader
Dim dr2 As SqlDataReader
Dim strSQL As String
Dim intRec As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim k As Integer
Dim gintRefresh As Integer
Dim gintDayID As Integer
Dim gstrWavFile As String = "C:\buzzer.wav"
Dim myTable As DataTable
Dim gintBlinkCnt As Integer
Dim gintLoopRec As Integer
Dim gintFlip As Integer
Dim gzone As String
Dim gfoundRows() As DataRow
Dim gintTotal As Integer
Dim TMac, Wmac As String


Private Sub frmMain_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
  Try

     LocalDAL.ConnectionString = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings.Get("LocalDB")
        LocalDAL.Provider = EnumProviders.SQLClient
        Me.gintRefresh = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings.Get("Refresh(sec)")
        Me.gintLoopRec = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings.Get("LoopRec")
        Me.gzone = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings.Get("Zone")
        If Me.gzone <> "ALL" Then
            Me.lblPID.Text = Me.lblPID.Text & " [Zone: " & Me.gzone & "]"
        End If
        Me.tmrGrid.Interval = Me.gintRefresh * 1000
        Me.tmrGrid.Enabled = True
        Me.subDefineGrid()

    'setting up open location
    Me.SetDesktopLocation(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings.Get("Xpos"), 0)
    Me.Location = New Point(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings.Get("Xpos"), 0)
    Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized

    Catch ex As Exception
        Me.subErrLog("frmMain_Load", ex.Message)

  End Try
End Sub
...
```

Comment: I see that you're trying to pass a string to a structure that expects an integer, but of course you're counting on `Option Strict OFF`. Good luck. Anyway, read the notes here: [Using SetWindowPos with multiple monitors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53026765/7444103)

Comment: I thought so too. But I did try to replace the string with to become (1280, 0). But same issue.