# GetForegroundWindow() returns Explorer Id in some cases

Tags: c#, winapi

So I hooked the [GetForegroundWindow()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getforegroundwindow) method to the Windows global focus change events, to monitor the focus state of the main window of a third-party process, but it shows abnormal behavior.

If I focus application by clicking on its window with the mouse or pressing alt+tab, `GetForegroundWindow()` will return the corresponding window handle, it's all good.

But if I focus application by clicking on its icon on the taskbar, the method will return the Explorer handle and any further clicking on the application window won't change anything - the window is already focused, and Windows won't send any focus events anymore. It feels like Explorer has become the parent of the app.

But then if you press alt+tab 2 times, refocusing the application, `GetForegroundWindow()` would return a proper handle.

I've also tried to get window focus state through the [GetWindowInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowinfo) call, but it shows the same result.

Please help, what is wrong with Explorer or what am I doing wrong?

```csharp
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr SetWinEventHook(uint eventMin, uint eventMax, IntPtr hmodWinEventProc, WinEventDelegate lpfnWinEventProc, uint idProcess, uint idThread, uint dwFlags);

public delegate void WinEventDelegate(IntPtr hWinEventHook, uint eventType, IntPtr hwnd, int idObject, int idChild, uint dwEventThread, uint dwmsEventTime);

private const uint EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND = 0x0003;
private const uint EVENT_SYSTEM_CAPTURESTART = 0x0008;
private const uint WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT = 0x0000;
private WinEventDelegate _focusDelegate;
private IntPtr _focusChangedHookPointer;

// It's const like this only for StackOverflow. I just simplified everything.
private IntPtr MY_WINDOW_HANDLE = 1315754;

private void FocusChangedHook(IntPtr hWinEventHook, uint eventType, IntPtr hwnd, int idObject, int idChild, uint dwEventThread, uint dwmsEventTime)
{
    var foregroundWindowHandle = GetForegroundWindow();
    Debug.WriteLine($"Handle Id: {foregroundWindowHandle}"); 
    Debug.WriteLine($"Is Foreground: {foregroundWindowHandle == MY_WINDOW_HANDLE}");
}

private void Start()
{
    _focusDelegate = FocusChangedHook;
    _focusChangedHookPointer = SetWinEventHook(EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND, EVENT_SYSTEM_CAPTURESTART, IntPtr.Zero, _focusDelegate, 0, 0, WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT);
}
```

Comment: You'll have to describe this app better.  If it is for example an appx app then this is probably normal, returning the host window handle.  Have a look-see with Spy++.

Comment: @HansPassant, thx, I described my problem a little better. After re-reading I realized that I had described the problem a bit incorrectly and misled everyone. The interface of my application doesn't play any role, it doesn't exist at all, the problem is how the hook behaves

Comment: Why are you calling `GetForegroundWindow()`? `IntPtr hwnd` already tells you which Window has become the Foreground Window. That's its handle -- You also check `eventType` and set `WINEVENT_SKIPOWNPROCESS` / `WINEVENT_SKIPOWNTHREAD`  besides  `WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT`

Comment: This is a high-level hook not a low-level hook  in a DLL that attaches to all processes, so my guess is it stops receiving focus change events after it stops being the focused app.  Similar to WM_ACTIVATEAPP.  You might need to use a timer event and poll GetForegroundWindow instead,

Comment: @DaveS `GetForegroundWindow()` returns the handle of the Window that has already become the Foreground Window, not the one that *is going to become*. As mentioned, the `hwnd` parameter of the callback already references the handle of the Window that is coming to the foreground -- The OP is also subscribing to a range of events, without checking the `eventType`

Comment: @Jimi Yeah, you are right, the code looks a bit odd. But I just checked and `hwnd` returns the same Explorer handle just like the `GetForegroundWindow()`. So it's not that. And the event range has a certain length to capture all the events related to the focus. I don't care which event of them would trigger, I only need to capture the first one of those that trigger

Comment: Those events include Menu activation / popup. As mentioned, you have to instruct to skip your Thread, check the event Type and whether `idObject = OBJID_WINDOW`. Depending on the circumstances, also checking what `idChild` is set to won't hurt (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48812831/7444103), for example) -- It wouldn't also hurt if you described the nature of your application and System version where this app is tested

Comment: @Jimi - my point is that app switching can change the foreground window more than once, and I think this approach only shows the first change.  That first change will be the OS window for some methods of changing the app.  App1 => OS window => App2.  If you want to see App2, polling will work.

Comment: @DaveS The only case (I'm aware of) when the foreground window can change more than once is when you ALT+TAB / WIN+TAB, because, well, a couple of windows are moved to the foreground, in sequence. `GetWindowThreadProcessId()` can help here, since you most probably already know the Process ID of the application you're *watching* (but you also have `dwEventThread`). If you're not watching a specific application, that's probably useful information anyway

Comment: @Jimi Thank you so much, your leading questions gave me an idea and by checking it I found where to look for the problem. I can't believe I spent so much time trying to find the answer that was lying in plain sight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This anomalous hook behavior was due to the fact that I was attaching my program to a Unity application, which at some point when launching the game world seemed to recreate its window and force it to focus while being minimized, resulting in some messed up behavior with the Windows foreground event, or something like that.

I don't know how it works all the way inside Unity, but I'm gonna go look into it. For all other applications, my code works just fine. Gj Unity.

I "semi-fixed" it by also hooking up to the window minimization event, and then performing checks combining these two states.

Once again, thank you guys for you answers, and a special thanks to [@Jimi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7444103/jimi) for the leading questions, code slandering, and the clues, you've made my day.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [Application.Activated Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.application.activated?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) instead of the focus.

Comment: This is for full-fledged applications. I need to find and then monitor the focus state of the main window of a third-party process